# Using variables in javascript css property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am relatively new to Javascript, and am trying to make a simple game in which a meteor falls at a random rate. My issue is that, every time the for loop plays, the meteor div should be add math to its distance from the top, but I have no idea how to do this. Take a look at the current code and you'll see that #meteor animates with 'math'. This code doesn't work. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Thank you, input is appreciated!

```
var math = Math.round(Math.random * 5)
        for(var i = 0; i <= height / 3; i++) {
            $('#meteor').animate({top: "+=math"}, 1)
        }
```

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please? Also, have you tried `{top: +=math}`?

Comment: You are setting the *top* property to the string `"+=math"`, what do you actually want to do?

Comment: @j08691—a compound assignment has to assign to something, it can't be used like that.

Comment: @RobG - yup, left my quotes out. Should read `top: '+='+math`. Also, the OP left out `()` in `Math.round(Math.random * 5);`. Should be `Math.round(Math.random() * 5);`

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add () to Math.random!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following one

```
 for(var i = 0; i <= height / 3; i++) {
    var math = Math.round(Math.random * 5)
    $('#meteor').animate({top: "+="+math}, 1);
 }
```

Comment: @Rusty25, Glad its work for you, then please mark as answer and upvote

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things. Whenever you surround anything in JS with quotes, it is treated as a string, so even though you have the variable `math`, because it is in quotes it is treated as the string `'math'`. The other thing is `+=` has to have something come before it in order to work and can't be used with jQuery in the way you're trying to.

To simple get your code working, change it to this:

```
var math = Math.round(Math.random * 5)
for(var i = 0; i <= height / 3; i++) {
    // Gives the 'top' value for meteor. parseInt removes the
    // 'px' that will show up on the end and return type int
    var meteorTop = parseInt($('#meteor').css('top')); 
    $('#meteor').animate({top: meteorTop + math}, 1);
}
```

That said, your animations are going to overlap and you're going to want to wait between animations or else they will trigger on top of each other and not work the way you want them to.

Only kind of related, a situation in which `+=` works is this:

```
var int = 0;
int += 2; // int = 2; this is the same as: int = int + 2;
int += 3; // int = 5; this is the same as: int = int + 3;
```

You should add the same type to itself, JS will do some interpretation for you, but you should always use `+=` with the same type. `string += string` or `int += int`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to increment the value of *top* by *math* on each iteration, then you want something like:

```
  $('#meteor').animate({top: math * i}, 1)
```